# Como exibir imagens dinamicamente a partir de um array no vuetify?

Tags: imagem, vue.js, vuetify

Pessoal que conhece de Vue/Vuetify, estou com dificuldades para mostrar imagens em uma tag  de forma dinamica.

A situação é a seguinte. Eu tenho um array declarado no "data" que contem vários objetos, e cada um desses objetos tem um endereço para uma imagem. Abaixo está esse array:

```
todasAsCartas:[
            { 'id': 1,         'nome': 'Dois de Ouros',        'valor': 2,       'naipe': 'Ouros',         'images': { 'img': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdeouros.png')}  },
            { 'id': 2,         'nome': 'Três de Ouros',        'valor': 3,       'naipe': 'Ouros',         'images': { 'img': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdeouros.png')}  },
            { 'id': 3,         'nome': 'Quatro de Ouros',      'valor': 4,       'naipe': 'Ouros',         'images': { 'img': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdeouros.png')}  },
            { 'id': 4,         'nome': 'Cinco de Ouros',       'valor': 5,       'naipe': 'Ouros',         'images': { 'img': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdeouros.png')}  },
            { 'id': 5,         'nome': 'Seis de Ouros',        'valor': 6,       'naipe': 'Ouros',         'images': { 'img': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdeouros.png')}  },
            { 'id': 6,         'nome': 'Sete de Ouros',        'valor': 7,       'naipe': 'Ouros',         'images': { 'img': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdeouros.png')}  },
            { 'id': 7,         'nome': 'Oito de Ouros',        'valor': 8,       'naipe': 'Ouros',         'images': { 'img': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdeouros.png')}  },
            { 'id': 8,         'nome': 'Nove de Ouros',        'valor': 9,       'naipe': 'Ouros',         'images': { 'img': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdeouros.png')}  },
            { 'id': 9,         'nome': 'Dez de Ouros',         'valor': 10,      'naipe': 'Ouros',         'images': { 'img': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdeouros.png')}  },
            { 'id': 10,        'nome': 'Dama de Ouros',        'valor': 11,      'naipe': 'Ouros',         'images': { 'img': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdeouros.png')}  },
            { 'id': 11,        'nome': 'Valete de Ouros',      'valor': 12,      'naipe': 'Ouros',         'images': { 'img': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdeouros.png')}  },
            { 'id': 12,        'nome': 'Reis de Ouros',        'valor': 13,      'naipe': 'Ouros',         'images': { 'img': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdeouros.png')}  },
            { 'id': 13,        'nome': 'Ás de Ouros',          'valor': 14,      'naipe': 'Ouros',         'images': { 'img': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdeouros.png')}  },
            { 'id': 14,        'nome': 'Dois de Espadas',      'valor': 2,       'naipe': 'Espadas',       'images': { 'img': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdeouros.png')}  },
            { 'id': 15,        'nome': 'Três de Espadas',      'valor': 3,       'naipe': 'Espadas',       'images': { 'img': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdeouros.png')}  },
            { 'id': 16,        'nome': 'Quatro de Espadas',    'valor': 4,       'naipe': 'Espadas',       'images': { 'img': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdeouros.png')}  },
            { 'id': 17,        'nome': 'Cinco de Espadas',     'valor': 5,       'naipe': 'Espadas',       'images': { 'img': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdeouros.png')}  },
            { 'id': 18,        'nome': 'Seis de Espadas',      'valor': 6,       'naipe': 'Espadas',       'images': { 'img': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdeouros.png')}  },
            { 'id': 19,        'nome': 'Sete de Espadas',      'valor': 7,       'naipe': 'Espadas',       'images': { 'img': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdeouros.png')}  },
            { 'id': 20,        'nome': 'Oito de Espadas',      'valor': 8,       'naipe': 'Espadas',       'images': { 'img': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdeouros.png')}  },
            { 'id': 21,        'nome': 'Nove de Espadas',      'valor': 9,       'naipe': 'Espadas',       'images': { 'img': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdeouros.png')}  },
            { 'id': 22,        'nome': 'Dez de Espadas',       'valor': 10,      'naipe': 'Espadas',       'images': { 'img': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdeouros.png')}  },
            { 'id': 23,        'nome': 'Dama de Espadas',      'valor': 11,      'naipe': 'Espadas',       'images': { 'img': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdeouros.png')}  },
            { 'id': 24,        'nome': 'Valete de Espadas',    'valor': 12,      'naipe': 'Espadas',       'images': { 'img': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdeouros.png')}  },
            { 'id': 25,        'nome': 'Reis de Espadas',      'valor': 13,      'naipe': 'Espadas',       'images': { 'img': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdeouros.png')}  },
            { 'id': 26,        'nome': 'Ás de Espadas',        'valor': 14,      'naipe': 'Espadas',       'images': { 'img': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdeouros.png')}  },
            { 'id': 27,        'nome': 'Dois de Copas',        'valor': 2,       'naipe': 'Copas',         'images': { 'img': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdeouros.png')}  },
            { 'id': 28,        'nome': 'Três de Copas',        'valor': 3,       'naipe': 'Copas',         'images': { 'img': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdeouros.png')}  },
            { 'id': 29,        'nome': 'Quatro de Copas',      'valor': 4,       'naipe': 'Copas',         'images': { 'img': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdeouros.png')}  },
            { 'id': 30,        'nome': 'Cinco de Copas',       'valor': 5,       'naipe': 'Copas',         'images': { 'img': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdeouros.png')}  },
            { 'id': 31,        'nome': 'Seis de Copas',        'valor': 6,       'naipe': 'Copas',         'images': { 'img': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdeouros.png')}  },
            { 'id': 32,        'nome': 'Sete de Copas',        'valor': 7,       'naipe': 'Copas',         'images': { 'img': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdeouros.png')}  },
            { 'id': 33,        'nome': 'Oito de Copas',        'valor': 8,       'naipe': 'Copas',         'images': { 'img': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdeouros.png')} },
            { 'id': 34,        'nome': 'Nove de Copas',        'valor': 9,       'naipe': 'Copas',         'images': { 'img': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdeouros.png')} },
            { 'id': 35,        'nome': 'Dez de Copas',         'valor': 10,      'naipe': 'Copas',         'images': { 'img': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdeouros.png')} },
            { 'id': 36,        'nome': 'Dama de Copas',        'valor': 11,      'naipe': 'Copas',         'images': { 'img': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdeouros.png')} },
            { 'id': 37,        'nome': 'Valete de Copas',      'valor': 12,      'naipe': 'Copas',         'images': { 'img': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdeouros.png')} },
            { 'id': 38,        'nome': 'Reis de Copas',        'valor': 13,      'naipe': 'Copas',         'images': { 'img': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdeouros.png')} },
            { 'id': 39,        'nome': 'Ás de Copas',          'valor': 14,      'naipe': 'Copas',         'images': { 'img': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdeouros.png')} },
            { 'id': 40,        'nome': 'Dois de Paus',         'valor': 2,       'naipe': 'Paus',          'images': { 'img': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdeouros.png')} },
            { 'id': 41,        'nome': 'Três de Paus',         'valor': 3,       'naipe': 'Paus',          'images': { 'img': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdeouros.png')} },
            { 'id': 42,        'nome': 'Quatro de Paus',       'valor': 4,       'naipe': 'Paus',          'images': { 'img': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdeouros.png')} },
            { 'id': 43,        'nome': 'Cinco de Paus',        'valor': 5,       'naipe': 'Paus',          'images': { 'img': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdeouros.png')} },
            { 'id': 44,        'nome': 'Seis de Paus',         'valor': 6,       'naipe': 'Paus',          'images': { 'img': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdeouros.png')} },
            { 'id': 45,        'nome': 'Sete de Paus',         'valor': 7,       'naipe': 'Paus',          'images': { 'img': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdeouros.png')} },
            { 'id': 46,        'nome': 'Oito de Paus',         'valor': 8,       'naipe': 'Paus',          'images': { 'img': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdeouros.png')} },
            { 'id': 47,        'nome': 'Nove de Paus',         'valor': 9,       'naipe': 'Paus',          'images': { 'img': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdeouros.png')} },
            { 'id': 48,        'nome': 'Dez de Paus',          'valor': 10,      'naipe': 'Paus,',         'images': { 'img': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdeouros.png')} },
            { 'id': 49,        'nome': 'Dama de Paus',         'valor': 11,      'naipe': 'Paus',          'images': { 'img': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdeouros.png')} },
            { 'id': 50,        'nome': 'Valete de Paus',       'valor': 12,      'naipe': 'Paus',          'images': { 'img': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdeouros.png')} },
            { 'id': 51,        'nome': 'Reis de Paus',         'valor': 13,      'naipe': 'Paus',          'images': { 'img': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdeouros.png')} },
            { 'id': 52,        'nome': 'Ás de Paus',           'valor': 14,      'naipe': 'Paus',          'images': { 'img': require('@/assets/cartas/doisdeouros.png')} }

        ],
```

quando eu rodo a aplicação, ele não mostra as imagens da carta. No template, o código para mostrar este array é esse:

```
<h3 class="ma-4">Baralho</h3>
<v-card class="ma-4 pa-2"  v-for="carta in todasAsCartas" :key="carta.images">
  <v-card width="50px">
    <v-img :src="carta.images.img" aspect-ratio="0.8" max-height="60px" max-widht="30px"></v-img>
  </v-card>
</v-card>
```

Comment: Pode ser mais claro em sua dúvida?

Comment: o :key tem que ser único, então altere para :key="carta.id", as outras informações são mostradas? tem alguma coisa no console?

Comment: md_rss 1:
Eu fiz o que você falou, e de uma certa maneira, funcionou. Só que agora eu estou com outro problema. Estou tentando tirar um objeto desse array "todasAsCartas" e enviar à uma outra array, "cartasDoPlayer1", só que eu quero que quando eu mando ele não exibe a imagem da carta, ele dá erro de "Cannot read property 'img' of undefined". Saberia dizer o por quê?